# facebook page insights

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to receive facebook page insights, i mean, the most popular age group, like here, but using Facebook Graph API?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way,

https://graph.facebook.com/%%PAGE_ID%%/insights/page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique/%%DATE%%

Specify %%PAGE_ID%% with your own Page id
%%DATE%% can either be:
day
week
days_28

now that will give you an array, from there on you will need to use PHP or other programming language that you use to get data from the array compare and show the end user which one is the more popular.

The same you can do also with demographics most popular city,
just use page_impressions_by_country_unique

like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/%%PAGE_ID%%/insights/page_impressions_by_country_unique/%%DATE%%

Same implies here, change %%PAGE_ID%% and %%DATE%% to your liking :)

Hope this helps.

Use developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ to trie some other features ;)